# Free library to MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-office

I need open source or free to commercial use library, which can get data from MS Word file. I think about LibreOffice. Do you know somethning else?

I'm interested in DOC file (version 97-2003) and library should be 64bit.

Can I use to commercial purposes

Comment: Which version of Office was used to Create the documents? Some APIs (like the OpenXML SDK) allow for working with newer versions of Office but don't provide backward compatibility.

Comment: free https://docx.codeplex.com and trial http://netword.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found nice library NetOffice (http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) which can cooperate with any file from MS office. (Word, Excel, Powerpoint etc.)
To correct work library need installed MS Office

Comment: Thanks for posting back what you found that works reading the DOC binary format!

Answer (score 3):

Download [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) for reading Office Documents such as **MS Word**.

Comment: This library doesn't support old DOC file (binary files)

Answer (score 3):

Check out NPOI (A .NET Port of the Apache NOI API):

http://npoi.codeplex.com/

Comment: NPOI it fine library. Do you know any tutorials or examples with usage DOC file.