# Save text with emoji to file become '?'

Tags: c#, text, emoji

### What I have to do

I have to create a text file (`.txt, .doc,` ...) with the exact text passed (so with emojis) by a `.net` WebaApi (and attach it to an email).

### Situation:

I have a project with .net webapi. One of my routes consist of *creating a text file and attach it to an email, with some text passed by a device that may contain emojis*.

I can't figure out how to save emojis correctly. If I copy-paste an emoji into a word or notepad file it works, but if I save it through my code it doesn't. I suppose it is due to formatting, but I tried `Unicode, UTF-32, UTF-8, ASCII`,...

I tried many solutions found here on SO, but none of them worked for me.

For example this emoji (copy-pasted from .net debugger) -->  is converted into quotation mark or `¶ó`, based on encoding used.

How can I save emoji as text into a file so that they can be read by the receivers?

This is what I've done:

```
//smsText is a string containing emojis
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(smsText);
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), tokenKey + ".doc");
attachment.ContentType = new ContentType("application/ms-word");
List <Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
attachments.Add(attachment);
//send email with attachments
```

Note that smsText, with debugger, contains the  correctly displayed.

The email correctly reach the receiver, with the .doc attachment, but the attachment doesn't contains the emojis

Comment: How are you generating the `.doc` file?

Comment: @john I don't save it to file, I just use the above code to create an attachment with the given text and `contenttype = application/ms-word`

Comment: So you're generating a text file in-memory, not a Word document?

Comment: If you are creating a text file your content type should be "text/plain" and the file extension ".txt".

Comment: You can't just save a text string and call it a Word file.

Comment: @CodeCaster actually Word tries to interpret text files as well, but as you can see this creates more issues than anything

Comment: I write only a reply for all :) I don't save anything on file system. I just create an attachment to an email with the .doc extension (I tried also the .txt) but in both cases, the emojis are not shown on the file

Comment: Pier In case it isn't already clear, we're using "file" to refer to the binary data that will become a file once the attachment is saved, since its intended purpose is a file but it just happens to be stored in memory. You might have to set a `TransferEncoding` value on the `Attachment` object to get it to send through correctly, or prefix the content with a UTF8 byte order mark (BOM).

Comment: @john Oh I didn't got it sorry. Btw your comment and CodeCaster 's answer got me solve my problem! Now I use a .txt file with UTF8 encoding. I didn't know that I could not just use attachment contenttype to create a word document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `smsText` contains a plaintext string. You can't just write that string into a stream or file that you then call a Word file<sup>*</sup>.

Word files are binary files with a specific format. You need to use a library that can write this format, or use Interop to interoperate with an existing Word installation.

See for example [Free library to MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675816/free-library-to-ms-word).

And if you're fine with plaintext files, just write the text's bytes to a stream and propagate the appropriate encoding (in this case Unicode, being UTF-16 on .NET).

<sub><sup>*</sup>: yes you can, just like that Excel tries its best to format an HTML table as an Excel document, but you shouldn't.</sub>

Comment: +1 for suggesting a Word library. But I just want to add that if you don't care about the old `.doc` format and can use the new `.docx` format you probably want to search for Open XML libraries instead. [DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX) is a great library that I have used in the past.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got solved with your first line + John's comment. If possible, to complete the answer, add his comment to specify what to do with the .txt format instead. Thanks again

Comment: @Pier I don't know what you mean by that. Do you mean you can write a plaintext .txt file instead and it works?

Comment: @CodeCaster I think it might have been using `UTF8` instead of `Unicode`.

Comment: @CodeCaster yeah, sorry if I was unclear. I wanted to say that I'm fine creating both a `.txt` or a `.doc/.docx` attachment with no preferences. If I use plain text with .txt format and UTF8 encoding format, it works.